# Toolbar disappears when hiding the perspective bar

Tags: eclipse-plugin, perspective, eclipse-rap

In my application I don't want to show the perspective bar so in `preWindowOpen()` method I set `configurer.setShowPerspectiveBar(false);` but the whole toolbar disappears too. I also set `configurer.setShowCoolBar(true);`

And this is my toolbar:

```xml
<menuContribution
        locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.trim.command2">
            <toolbar
                ...
            </toolbar>
```

I don't know why it happen so I leave my question here.

Answer (score 0):

The main toolbar is `org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar` so you must use that id in your `locationURI`.

Comment: It's the same when I changed `locationURI` to `org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar`. Thanks for your answer.